# How to extract data from nested object with pug

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to access data from nested JSON object without any javascript in PUG and product.highlights[0].heading , the index needs to looped.

JSON FORMAT

```
[{"id":"0.33454785604755677","title":"Product 2 Title",
"highlights":[
- {"heading":"Product 2 Heading 1","description":"Product 2 Description 1"},
 - {"heading":"","description":""},
 - {"heading":"","description":""},
 - {"heading":"","description":""}]
}]
```

I tried

```
-var x = [0,1,2,3,4,5] 
-var high =[product.highlights[0].heading,product.highlights[1].heading,product.highlights[2].heading,product.highlights[3].heading] 
each val in x 
 -var p = high[x] // here its not considering 'x' 
  h3 #{p}
```

and directly using loop too

```
each i in [0,1,2,3,4,5]
 h3 #{product.highlights[i].heading} //but here its not considering 'i'
```

Its working inside 'name' , 'for' .

but i need it to work inside:

```
- value=(editing ? product.highlights[0].heading:'')


each i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  .form-control
  label(for="highlights[" + i +"][heading]") Highlights Number #{i} Heading
  input(type="text",name="highlights[" + i +"][heading]",value=(editing ? product.highlights[0].heading:''))
```

I don't know how to access it through javascript in pug

Can someone tell me how can i do that?

Comment: I have tried to replicate this in a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pacific202/pen/ZZxMXy), but I can't understand exactly what you're trying to do.  Could you please go back and edit your question to show what the desired HTML output needs to be?  You should also remove references to variables like `editing` and `product` as they don't exist anywhere else in your code.  Please see how to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Graham
thanks alot though i figured it out already.

Comment: @UtkarshTomar Glad you got it figured out. Can you post the solution as an answer below so that others may benefit from it?

Comment: @Graham I posted my solution, I'm pretty sure it should've worked without creating a function too,i.e using this inside each loop --> ( product.highlights[i].heading ) instead of calling a function which does this... but idk atlast this is the way it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
-function productHeading(product,y){return product.highlights[y].heading;}

 each i in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
   .form-control
       label(for="highlights[" + i +"][heading]") Highlights Number #{i+1} Heading
          input(type="text",name="highlights[" + i +"][heading]",value=(editing ? productHeading(product,i):''))
```

product stores the object found by findById method which later sent to the pug file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubProductSchema = new Schema({

    product_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    title: String,
    name:{
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    price:Number,
    image:String,
    alt: String,
    quantity:Number,
    description:String,
    bgImage:String,
    primaryImage:String,
    primaryAlt: String,
    primaryHeading:String,
    primaryDescription:String,
    highlights:[{
        heading:String,
        description:String,
        icon:String
    }],
    specs:[{
        heading:String,
        description:String,
        image:String
    }],


    featured:Boolean,
    preOrder:Boolean,
    video:Boolean
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('xxx',xxx);
```

Controller File

```
const Product = require('../models/product');
.
.
Product.findById(prodId)
        .then( product => { ....
```

And so on .
Editing is a boolean variable , if its true the productHeading function in pug file is called and value is initalized to it else its set to '' (empty)